# Adobe acrobat action wizard copy file to directory

Tags: javascript, acrobat

Using Adobe Acrobat Pro I need a way to simply COPY the open file to a SPECIFIC PRESET directory on the filesystem. By adding a button or something inside the program in the toolbar or sidebar.

What is the absolute easiest way to do this?

Can you add your own custom buttons in the "share tab" for example?

My thought was to use the Action Wizard and use javascript to copy the PDF to another directory. But I don't know javascript.

Does anyone know a solution to this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this was easier than I thought.

You simply create a new action in "action wizard" then just select "Save to" your directory on the filesystem. You do not even need any javascript to do this.

The only problem I have is how do I put the action in the toolbar? It can only be found under "Action Wizard" tab.